# Perl + one-liner smart Perl command, in place grep to match unusual characters + full match

Tags: perl

Subject: [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) smart Perl command instead of a simple [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (in Bash script)

I have a problem when I use grep to match the unusual characters (I can't put the "\" before each unusual character, because it's very problematic and not a smart solution).

I need Perl one-liner syntax that match exactly all the unusable characters as defined in the $Some_string. Examples: 

```
Examples

Some_string="[234-094]"
Some_string="[ * ( & % @ !]"
Some_string="~ [ 0:3 # % & ^ + =]"
Some_string="1.1.1.1.-9.9.9.9   + 9999.999.1 – 10000"
Some_string="< { [ ' : ; " ? / . , "
Some_string="PORT.A.B.C.D – 124.543.455.33 – [ ! NOT EQUAL PORT 38737 – 3837652"
.
.
.
```

My bad grep syntax

```
 cat  file | grep $Some_string
```

With Perl (I need the following right suggestion/solution):

```
 cat file | perl -nle 'print if /$Some_string/'
```

#### Rules

Remark: if Some_string="111.111.111.111"
        and in the file I have 1111.1111.1111.1111
        then the Perl syntax needs to ignore this.
        Perl must match only if I have this in the file: 111.111.111.111 .

Second remark: if Some_string="WORD"
            and in the file I have: ONEWORD
            then the Perl syntax needs to ignore this.
            Perl must match only if I have this in the file: WORD

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question, exactly. Perhaps `-P` and `-x` do what you want, along with quoting `"$Some_string"` to preserve whitespace?

```
grep -Px "$Some_string" file
```

From the grep man page:

> #### `-P`, `--perl-regexp`
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
>
> #### `-x`, `--line-regexp`
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.

Comment: please advice about the perl , I think perl is more safe

Comment: You need to explain your problem better. I don't understand what you're trying to do, nor how Perl will help. Please add some examples or something.

Comment: please see the Some_string examples , I need to perfrom cat file and to match the $Some_string , but with perl only - one line syntax , also see my last remark

Comment: like this:   cat file | perl ……../$Some_string/

Comment: @jon: Do you know about `quotemeta()`, or its double-quoted string-escape version, `\Q...\E`?

Comment: no I dont but please give me example , I think "\Q" and "E" are the part of my perl solution -:)

Comment: @jon, you’re going to have to tell us what part of [*perlre*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)’s discussion of `\Q` and *perlfunc* ’s corresponding description of [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) it is is that you *don’t* understand in the examples included there about this particular matter. You’ll need [some command-line switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches]) for a one-liner; these are documented in the *perlrun* manpage on your own system.

Comment: OK I find the follwoing  perl -nle 'print if /\Q$ENV{Some_string}/' but how to match exactly the string?

Comment: for example if in file I have 1.node_name and Some_string=node_name then it will match but I dont want to match 1.node_name ? what to do?

Comment: another example if I have in the file 11.11.11 and I want to match 1.1.1 in this case my perl syntax will match this also -:(

Comment: please see the RULES in my quastion.

Comment: @jon - Have you tried this `grep -Px` command? If it doesn't do what you want please give examples of strings that don't work.

Comment: grep x also match spaces , this is the reason that I cant use grep -x

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape the string somehow. Using `\` to escape special characters is required in this case, because passing the string to Perl is really no different than passing it to grep -- both will see the string after the shell processes it.

Using Perl to do this will simply obfuscate your code.

Comment: sorry I dont want to use with "\" please advice about perl.

Comment: You have no choice.  If you are going to pass these special characters to perl, **you will still have to escape them**.

Comment: I dont think so, because perl have special re to ignore the unusable char

Comment: Yes, but you still have to pass the string containing the characters to perl.  And if you use characters that the **shell** wants to interpret (like `"`) you *still* have to escape them.

Comment: `perl -nle 'BEGIN { $pat = shift || die } print if /\Q$pat/' pattern_with_ugly_things_in_it file1 file2 file666`

Comment: You're still going to have to escape characters in the pattern.

Comment: your perl syntax not have the rules that need to match exactly the string

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
perl -ne 'print if m|\Q[ * ( & % \E\@\Q !]\E|' file
```

I've found the \Q and \E operator in *[Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)*.

A snippet from that link:

> You cannot include a literal $ or @ within a \Q sequence. An unescaped $ or @ interpolates the corresponding variable, while escaping will cause the literal string \$ to be inserted. You'll need to write something like m/\Quser\E@\Qhost/.
>
> ```
> \Q  Quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E or
>     end of string
>
> \E  End either case modification or quoted section
>     (whichever was last seen)
> ```

Comment: hi - Unrecognized switch: -E ( the E flag isnt valid in the perl syntax)

Comment: It worked fine with Perl v5.28.1 (stock [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine))). The output was one line, `Some_string="[ * ( & % @ !]"`. Though it also appeared as if there was an empty line after that line.