# perl one line + exactly match

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [perl + one line smart perl command, in place grep to match unusual characters + full match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208235/perl-one-line-smart-perl-command-in-place-grep-to-match-unusual-characters-f)

Ai all

I need to match exactly the PARAMETER string with the following perl line:

```
 cat file  | perl -nle 'print if /\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}/'
```

As the following examples, showing down

I try to match: node_name

but I get all node_name combinations names from the file,

The same about 1.1.1. and host_1.A etc…

how to match exactly the following PARAMETERS ? from the file
, what need to change in my perl syntax in order to give the right match?

```
 more file
 param1=uplicateParam node_name
 param2=a anode_name 
 param3=bnode_name 
 param4node_name 
 param5=1.node_name 
 param6=11.11.11.11  
 param7=1.1.1.11
 param8=[1234]
 param9=* * * [@]
 param10=11.1.1.11
 param11=host_1.A
 param12=old.host_1.A


 example1

 PARAMETER=node_name
 export  PARAMETER
 cat file  | perl -nle 'print if /\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}/'

 DuplicateParam node_name
 a anode_name 
 bnode_name 
 node_name 
 1.node_name 


 Example2


 PARAMETER=1.1.1.1
 export  PARAMETER
 cat file  | perl -nle 'print if /\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}/'

 param7=1.1.1.11
 param10=11.1.1.11

 example3

 PARAMETER=host_1.A
 cat file  | perl -nle 'print if /\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}/'
 export  PARAMETER

 host_1.A
 old.host_1.A
```

Comment: not duplicate because this question is about perl match , second I dont get answer , third I must give more examples

Answer (score 0):

How can This line:

```
param2=a anode_name
```

being grepped for `node_name` yield `a anode_name`

while this line:

```
param7=1.1.1.11
```

being grepped for `1.1.1.1` yield `param7=1.1.1.11`

It seems to me that either the first should yield `param2=a anode_name` or the second should yield `1.1.1.11`

Comment: @rster -  what need to change in my perl syntax in order to give the right match?

Comment: @jon, I know this isn't the answer, because you are asking for contradictory output.  I personally think you should do `print $1 if (/^param\d+=(.*($ENV{PARAMETER}).*)/`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put word boundaries (`\b`) bto match exactly:

```
cat file  | perl -nle 'print if /\b\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}\b/'
```

Comment: Careful: boundaries specified with `\b` often fail to do [what most people think they do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nlE 'say if /\Aparam\d+=\Q$ENV{PARAMETER}\E\s*\z/' file
```